# Spacing Text firebase

Tags: flutter

welcome guys
I have a long text copied from a site and stored
In firebase and I want to put it in my application, but the problem is that firebase deletes the spaces in the texts, so when I put it in the text in my comment, it becomes not spaced
How do I make the text appear

### [the Frist picture in firebase here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWAu4.png)    2  [the second picture in site here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m36cu.png)

Comment: Please provide some context, what you've tried, and an example of code.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the problem is and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @danwebb i edited The first picture of the firebase, the texts, do not have the order of those on the site

The location is in the second photo

I'm new to stackoverflow so I don't know how to use it well

Comment: @LukeOlender The first picture of the firebase, the texts, do not have the order of those on the site

The location is in the second photo

I'm new to stackoverflow so I don't know how to use it well

Comment: It looks like it’s spaced to me in the Flutter console as well? But I don’t know that language, and Im afraid I don’t know what the solution could be.

Comment: Guessing from the pictures, it looks like the enters are being removed. Is is the problem? If so you can add a `\n` (new line character) after each line. Inside Firebase it will sill look like one big text but flutter will put the text on a new line.